# How to get out of IT?

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom

I am currently almost three years deep into an IT career as a java programmer, and I absolutely hate it. I have an advanced degree (in theatre of all things), but it seems that whenever I look online for job openings it is ALL IT. Am I just looking in the wrong place?

How can I focus my job search to find more creative, non-technical listings?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type of job you’re looking for? I experienced the same thing when I was in my early 20s. Now, low and behold, I work in IT.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the 'generic'  sites. Indeed, Totaljobs...

Comment: Maybe you need to work to and by yourself. Maybe yout problem is not programming in Java but rather building things you don't want to build rather than building the things you dreams to build

Comment: @jean Quite the opposite. The things I work on are quite big and relevant. I just don't like how it is so complicated and different all the time - you can never settle into a pattern of activity.

Comment: @WeckarE. Nice to know. I myself love to do have a different complicated thing to do everyday. Maybe you can look for a more "stable" routine like teaching or go back to the  academia

Comment: Job board sites generally try to "help" you by building a profile based on your past search keywords; in your situation this is the opposite of helpful. Try another job board, try creating a new profile, use a different computer, use private browsing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not all IT.

Search generic websites for specific phrases.  Go to websites that are specific to the field you want to work in.

Google "xxxx jobs".

It's not that hard to find jobs that aren't IT related.

Comment: From what I can tell, all the big ones (Indeed, Reed, Totaljobs, etc) all specialise in IT.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for jobs in the required field/role?

Comment: Doesn't that come with the risk of only finding ancient listings?

Comment: @WeckarE. yes, but so what?  I mean you run that risk at times using a website for IT jobs as well.  Depending on your goals, LinkedIn can be a good resource for you.

Comment: Occasionally.  But it also comes with the benefit of giving you websites where non-IT jobs exist....

Comment: @WeckerE Reed (and most any other big agency like them) also recruits for retail, hospitality, social care, warehouse, manufacturing, accounting, management, and more

Comment: Be careful searching for xxxx jobs. If you miss one character, it may be NSFW.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re looking on websites that match jobs to your experience, of course it’s going to be a lot of IT stuff because you’re currently a Java developer. Try creating a new profile and only list your non-technical skills, experience, and interests.

Most jobs aren’t listed online so your best bet may be to get out and network.

Comment: That's actually a smart idea, but that would require publishing a CV recruiters will see which then has a 3 year gap.

Comment: @WeckerE You have no skills except Java development in those three years? Don't have a gap - simply focus on the non-IT part of the job. Any leadership (even in a pair), initiative, planning, documentation, communication?

Comment: @HorusKol I got some UX experience, but certainly no management or directive skills of any kind.